# How do I download Ubuntu One files to my mac?

Tags: ubuntu-one, macosx

I have Ubuntu One files on my phone uploaded to the website because I own a mac. I'd like to download them all to said mac, how can I do that?

Do I really have to download every single file one by one?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, ther is no Ubuntu One cleint for OSX yet.

Comment: You may be able to use wget to download the files. http://askubuntu.com/questions/53223/use-wget-to-download-a-file-from-my-ubuntu-one-account-online-storage Perhaps someone who uses UbuntuOne can help you figure out how to do so recursively.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently maintaining an open source Ubuntu One client for OS X. Check it out on [Github](https://github.com/chrisledet/Uno).

Comment: Yes. It fully syncs.

Comment: Chris,
Any chance you can build this for OSX 10.6?

Comment: I'll see what I can do this weekend. Watch the project for incoming changes.

Comment: Chris, what happened to this project? it seems to have disappeared...

Comment: I had to rename the project. Canonical didn't like that I used Ubuntu in the project's name. I updated the link with the correct URL. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

File synchronization on Apple products are not yet supported, but "only" Ubuntu, Windows and Android. The client is both free software and mostly platform agnostic, so it should be relatively easy to add support for OS X as well, but everything takes time.

The web interface doesn't support downloading folders (yet). In other words; yes, if you're using OS X you'll currently have to download the files one at a time -- unless you port the client yourself, or maybe you can find a third-party port.

Answer (score 2):

I could not get the Uno client to work so I wrote this python script which lets you download/update files on any platform: https://github.com/ddimmich/unbuntuone-python

Instructions are provided on github.

Answer (score 0):

We have released as of today a Mac OS X beta version which you can find here: http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/10/11/ubuntu-one-for-mac-os-x-now-in-beta/