# How to download a folder on ubuntu one ? mac

Tags: ubuntu-one, mac

Hello I've found here a [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53223/use-wget-to-download-a-file-from-my-ubuntu-one-account-online-storage) talking about wget.

I have looked for [installing wget in mac](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/07/installing-wget-on-your-mac-for-terminal.html).
Then, I tried to download the files using this command:

```
wget -nv --content-disposition (https://one.ubuntu.com/files/#f=f%2FUntitled%2520Folder)
```

It didn't work. (It downloaded some undetermined file of 1700 bytes.)

I then found this: http://lifehacker.com/161202/geek-to-live--mastering-wget and tried

```
wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.mp3 -erobots=off -i Lessonmp3.txt
```

[This](https://one.ubuntu.com/files/#f=f%2FUntitled%2520Folder) is the link to the Lessonmp3.txt.

I then tried

```
wget -A.mp3 -A.pdf (https://one.ubuntu.com/files/#f=f%2FUntitled%2520Folder)
```

It downloads the same 1700 byte file but deletes it afterwards.

I am quite computer illiterate. Please help!

Comment: A work-around that requires extra steps is to tar all the files in a folder and sync that tarball to Ubuntu One. Then, you can download this tarball with one-click on your Mac.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use wget the way you're trying to, I'm afraid. The Ubuntu One website requires you to be logged in to see your files; wget, because it's running from the command line and not in your browser, isn't logged in when it connects to the U1 website, and so can't see your files.

If you're using a recent version of Google Chrome, you may find http://kryogenix.org/days/2012/02/29/downloading-all-the-files-in-an-ubuntu-one-folder useful (please read the caveats!). If not, then I'm afraid that downloading the files in a folder individually by clicking each file is the way to fetch many files to a Mac, for now.